# Spring Boot PagingAndSortingRepository search: Combine multiple params for complex search

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

Hi I am trying to build a complex search endpoint within my REST-API. I have multibele parameters and like to compine them in a complex way. These are my Parameters:

```
@Param(value = "applicationId") String applicationId,
@Param(value = "mdName01") String mdName01,
@Param(value = "mdName02") String mdName02,
@Param(value = "mdName03") String mdName03,
@Param(value = "mdName04") String mdName04,
```

What I like to do is something like that:

```
findAllBy: applicationID AND (mdName1 OR mdName2 OR MdName3 OR MdName4)
```

Becaus I could not find something for the `()` I changed my statement to:

```
findAllBy: applicaionID AND mdName1 OR applicaionID AND mdName2 OR applicaionID AND mdName3 [...]
```

This is how my Method is looking now:

```
Page<vwFact> findAllByApplicationIdAndMdName01StartingWithOrApplicationIdAndMdName02StartingWithOrApplicationIdAndMdName03StartingWithOrApplicationIdAndMdName04StartingWith (
        @Param(value = "applicationId") String applicationId,
        @Param(value = "mdName01") String mdName01,
        @Param(value = "mdName02") String mdName02,
        @Param(value = "mdName03") String mdName03,
        @Param(value = "mdName04") String mdName04,
        Pageable pageable
);
```

Now when I run a request I get the following Error: `java.util.NoSuchElementException`, so it looks like I have used to little parameters.
So is there an easy fix for that or in general how am I used to implemented such complex search queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [@Query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html) for complex queries which is pretty easy to use.

Using @Query your code will look something like bellow code snippet.

```
@Query(SELECT v FROM vwFact v WHERE v.applicationId = :applicationId and v.mdName01 = :mdName01)
Page<vwFact> findAllByApplicationIdAndMdName01StartingWithOrApplicationIdAndMdName02StartingWithOrApplicationIdAndMdName03StartingWithOrApplicationIdAndMdName04StartingWith (
    @Param(value = "applicationId") String applicationId,
    @Param(value = "mdName01") String mdName01,
    @Param(value = "mdName02") String mdName02,
    @Param(value = "mdName03") String mdName03,
    @Param(value = "mdName04") String mdName04,
    Pageable pageable
```

);

Here is a nice [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query) to start with.